# Adjusting the CSS menu

Tags: html, css

Here is my menu test page with all the css:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.z-depth-0 {
    box-shadow: none !important
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 110, 115);
}

.dark-blue {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

nav .nav-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.right {
    float: right !important
}

#nav-mobile li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
}

#nav-mobile li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}

#nav-mobile li .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

#nav-mobile li:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

#nav-mobile .dropdown-button .dropdown-content li a {
    display: none;
}

#nav-mobile .dropdown-button:hover .dropdown-content li a {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dark-blue z-depth-0">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
            <li><a class='dropdown-button' href='#'>Links</a>
                <ul id="quicklinkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Access</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Zone</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class='dropdown-button' href='#'><span>User</span></a>
                <ul id="userdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="profile.html">My Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.html">Log Off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want the first `ul` menu to be right aligned on the page and I want the dropdown menu to be displayed with items one under the other when user hovers over Links or User. Instead, the dropdown content gets displayed in line. Can anyone help me fix the menu?

Also I want `Links` and `User` to be displayed a little higher

Comment: Are you implying that the above code is not doing these things and you would like to know why, or are you asking Stack Overflow users to write your code for you?

Comment: `display: inline-block;` is why they are displaying inline.

Comment: abney317, the top level `ul` items are inline-block, the two lover level `ul`'s items are just `block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position your items as relative and absolute. Parent items get a position: relative; and children get a position: absolute;

Best of luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Menu</title>

      <style>
         body {
            margin: 0;
          }

         .z-depth-0{box-shadow:none !important}

         nav {
             width: 100%;
             height: 56px;
             color: #fff;
        line-height: 56px;
           background-color: rgb(238, 110, 115);
         }

        .dark-blue {
             background-color: darkblue;
         }

        nav .nav-wrapper{
           height: 100%;
           position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
        .right {float: right!important}
        #nav-mobile li { 
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
        }

        #nav-mobile li a{ 
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;

         }

         #nav-mobile li .dropdown-content{ 
             display: none;
          }

          #nav-mobile li:hover .dropdown-content{ 
               display: block;
          }



         #nav-mobile .dropdown-button .dropdown-content li a { 
             display: none;}
        #nav-mobile .dropdown-button:hover .dropdown-content li a { 
            display: block;
        }

        ul#userdrop {
            /* right: 0; */
            /*left: 0;*/
            margin-left: -100px;
        }
        #nav-mobile li .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background: #000000;
        }
        #nav-mobile li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
        }
        .right {
            float: right!important;
            /* position: absolute; */
            /* right: 0; */
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        </style>

     </head>

      <body>
         <nav class="dark-blue z-depth-0">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">

               <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
                    <li><a class='dropdown-button' href='#'>Links</a>
                                <ul id="quicklinkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                                    <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Home</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Access</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#" style="color: red">Zone</a></li>
                                </ul>
                 </li>
                    <li><a class='dropdown-button' href='#'><span>User</span></a>
                <ul id="userdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="profile.html">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.html">Log Off</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok to get the options to display top down you want to add

```
#quicklinkdrop li{
                 display:list-item;
             }
 #userdrop li{
                 display:list-item;
             }
```

This should fix them being inline and put items on top of each other